# Record Link in a String Message Body in html email template

Tags: email-template

I would like to use an Account link in a contract object in html email template.The email is sent by using the String message body.
So when im using

```
   '<html><body>Hello  <br><b>SFDC : </b> <u>'+https://na1.salesforce.com/+'{!Contract.AccountId} </u> </body></html> '
```

the system keeps throwing an error as

> Error: Compile Error: expecting a semi-colon, found ':'

How can i do this.Any help very much appreciated.

Comment: You need to escape the `:` with a backslash like `\:`.

Comment: @crmprogdev:Thanks for your response.I didnt get your point .Yow mean in this way SFDC \' :\'.Any example very much appreciated.

Comment: No, just a single backslash before the colon as in `SFDC \:` No need for the single quotes since it's already encapsulated. Make certain you check the char number where the error is as it could also be at the link following https.